# Is Mono a .Net port?

Tags: c#, mono

Is Mono a .Net framework port to Linux, or is more fair to view it as just another Linux framework that happens to use C# which is an open standard? 
I never hear hear of wide spread Mono adaption

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Mono is definitely NOT a port (which would mean that Microsoft gave
>   the code and that it has been tweaked to run on Linux and other
>   platforms). Mono is an independent reimplementation of the .Net
>   framework (and a few other features and innovations on top of it)

Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. Mono can be used to make .net applications work in linux even though there will be some performance degradation and some other difficulties. Any way you can have the basic functionality. Currently, Mono supports just about everything available in .Net 2.0. There are a few notable exceptions, like Windows.Forms' DataGridView and ASP.Net's WebParts. There are also a couple of namespaces that don't really have a Linux equivalent like EnterpriseServices, System.Management, and System.Messaging.

The stated purpose of Mono is not only to be able to run Microsoft .NET applications cross-platform, but also to bring better development tools to Linux developers. Mono can be run on Android, BSD, iOS, Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, Solaris, and Unix operating systems as well as some game console operating systems such as the ones for the PlayStation 3, Wii, and Xbox 360.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_For_.Net_Developers

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I just wonder how practical something like this is, and how likely it is that enterprise level projects will go this route... I admire them for doing it though

Comment: They have found other good outlets for Mono, such as MonoMac, MonoTouch (iOS) and MonoDroid (Android).

Comment: @TGH: One of our enterprise level project has gone this route and is successful.

Comment: take a look at what is not supported in MONO before actually you try to port it.

Comment: I'll say that mono is pretty good, I'm using it at work in a big team and have been happy to use it for home projects, monodevelop is pretty good too.

Comment: oh sure it supports most of the features but still if you are about to port a big enterprise level project you have to make sure that all the functions you have used can be ported by mono

Comment: Mono is definitely NOT a port (which would mean that Microsoft gave the code and that it has been tweaked to run on Linux and other platforms). Mono is an independent reimplementation of the .Net framework (and a few other features and innovations on top of it).

Comment: okay i will update it. What i meant was It help to port .net apps into linux.